# Component throwing Error causes error (TS2786) "Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert a small React project to Typescript. I have this parent `App.tsx` component as below:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <MoviesContextProvider>
            <$Page>
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/:slug" element={<Details />} />
                <Route path="/search" element={<SearchResults />} />
                <Route path="/*" element={<NotFound />} />
              </Routes>
            </$Page>
          </MoviesContextProvider>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};
```

for the `/search` route, I try to render the `SearchResults` component and in that component, I make a call to the API and return the search results. If I get an error, I throw an `Error` so my `ErrorBoundary` handles it by showing an error message.

The `SearchResults` component looks like this:

```
const SearchResults = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    error: null,
    results: null,
    status: "idle",
  });

  const searchQuery = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("q");

  const searchMovies = async () => {
    setState({ ...state, status: "pending" });

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${API_URL}?q=${searchQuery}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${API_TOKEN}`,
          },
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        setState({
          ...state,
          error: new Error(response.status.toString()),
          status: "rejected",
        });
      } else {
        const { movies } = await response.json();

        setState({ ...state, results: movies, status: "resolved" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setState({ ...state, error, status: "rejected" });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    searchMovies();
  }, []);

  switch (state.status) {
    case "idle":
      return null;
    case "pending":
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    case "rejected":
      throw state.error; // THIS PART CAUSES THE ISSUE
    case "resolved":
      return (
        <>
          <h1>Search results for "{searchQuery}"</h1>
          {state.results ? (
            // List results
          ) : (
            <p>No results</p>
          )}
        </>
      );
  }
};
```

After trying to convert the code to TS, I started to get the

```
  TS2786: 'SearchResults' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element | null | undefined' is not a valid JSX element.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.
```

due to the fact the I am not returning an `Element` or `null` in the case of an error or bad response from the API.

I was wondering what's a good approach to solve the issue, thanks!